# How to retrieve DIV width in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, html

I want to retrieve and store a `<div>`'s `width` in a managed bean, so later I can use this information to scale generated images to that `width`.

Is there a way to do this in JSF 2.0?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<h:panelGroup layout="block">..</h:panelGroup>` generates a `<div>`, and so you will have a component.

But you can use EL to assign widths and height - `<div style="width: #{bean.width};"></div>`

**Update:** you seem to need to send this after the page is rendered. So your option is AJAX. Make an ajax call (depending on your JSF version there are different ways) to the server to update the bean.

Comment: Maybe a solution would be to pass client info via form `POST`, and then retrieve it.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you want, JS is maybe your best resort. You might want to elaborate the functional requirement more. I namely don't see why you want to do this server-side.

Comment: My app generates diagrams on server-side. I 'save' them as images, and so i want to scale them up to fit the `<div>` that displays content.

Comment: I know a solution would be to save the image in a fixed size, and then resize it to the `<div>`'s `width`; but I wanted to make and display the same size, so no resize needed. I will just go with the solution of making a larger image, and resizing it.